# The screen of Toast information is still displayed after I call mMediaRecorder.start() in the function onFinish() in CountDownTimer, why?

Tags: android

I use Toast.makeText in the function onTick in CountDownTimer to prompt a user left time before starting record screen.

In my mind, mMediaRecorder.start() will start work after the information of Toast.makeText disappeared, but in fact, the video record the information of Toast.makeText().

It seems that the window of Toast is displayed asynchronous, how can I  make mMediaRecorder.start() work after the window of Toast disappeared completely? Thanks!

```
private void DelayStartRecord(RecordArg mRecordArg){
            new  CountDownTimer(10*1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                String s="seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                Toast.makeText(mContext,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mMediaRecorder.start();
            }

        }.start();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to android documentation. `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` will display the toast for 2 second.

```
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

You are displaying every toast after 1 second and here each Toast take 2 second. That's why it Toast is still there even after count down finish.

Quick Fix:

```
 private Toast mToastText;     
 private void DelayStartRecord(RecordArg mRecordArg){
                new  CountDownTimer(10*1000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    String s="seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                    if(mToastText==null){
                       mToastText = Toast.makeText(activity, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }                    
                    mToastText.setText(s);
                    mToastText.show();
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    if(mToastText!=null){
                      mToastText.cancel();
                    }
                    mMediaRecorder.start();
                }

            }.start();
    }
```

Here the [official android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java) where these flags are defined.

Comment: Thanks!  but your code is still display the last 1s information window of mToastText.

Comment: Let me check once again.

Comment: Thanks,  but still display the last 1s information after I added the code   if(mToastText!=null){
                    mToastText.cancel();
                }

Comment: @HelloCW you mean last 1s information display more than 1 second?

Comment: It's every fast, no more than 1 second

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t understand  your problem. can you please explain it little more.

Comment: Thanks! Before my code display "seconds remaining: 3 -> seconds remaining: 2 -> seconds remaining: 1" in the record video, at present your code display "seconds remaining: 1" in the record video. It means that your code is still to display  the window of Toast, only duration is short.

Comment: @HelloCW can you please try [this code](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=a2MGQZYG). As you describe, problem seems like onFinish() called after sometime.

Comment: Thanks! You code  still display "seconds remaining: 1" in video, only duration  is more short!  I modify some of your code, would you please view at http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=hm3H2ZB5 , "seconds remaining: 1" will never be displayed again.

Comment: @HelloCW Happy to hear that you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Toast.makeText(mContext,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**LENGTH_SHORT** has a duration of 2.5 seconds. Where as you wanted to show the Toast every 1 second. So all the 10 Toasts(10 to 1 secs) are in queue and are shown for 2.5 secs each. Hence even after the 10 seconds count down, the Toast keeps showing for 15 more seconds.

Here is what you can do:
Create the Toast out side the CountDownTimer and use

```
toast.cancel;
String s="seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
toast.setText(s);
toast.show();
```

You can check the `makeText` method which creates a new Toast `Toast result = new Toast(context);` every time you call it.